# When editing UITableView, clicking red dot fails to display 'Delete' button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

A table view is contained in a regular view.
As expected, taping 'Edit' button (in that table view) displays 'red dot with minus sign' for each row (that is, method 'setEditing' executes OK).
However, clicking such red dot does NOT display the corresponding 'Delete' button ('commitEditingStyle' does NOT execute).
Any idea on what could be wrong (see relevant code below)?

```
//---- RootViewController.h ----
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {    //used to be a 'UITableViewController'. Changed to UIViewController and rewired so I could add an iAd banner and the tableView to it. Before that change, issue was not present (commitEditingStyle below used to work).
...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;   

//----- RootViewController.m ----
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; 
    ...
}
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {    //Added so clicking 'Edit' displays red dots that rotate on tap (as expected).
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];         
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing) {                                           
        NSLog(@"RootViewController setEditing");             //Executes OK.
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView                  //Clicking a red dot no longer executes this method (so, does not display 'Delete' red button).
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle  
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {         

    NSLog(@"RootViewController commitEditingStyle");           //Does NOT execute.
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the code that makes your table cells look like? How are they laid out?

Comment: Connections and cell: http://web.me.com/gguglielmo/Q/Q1.html

Comment: did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you've wired up both your table's `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` correctly to the new UIViewController you've written.

Comment: Connections and cell layout (in web.me.com/gguglielmo/Q/Q1.html )shows File Owner's outlets for dataSource and delegate are connected to the Table view. Table cells are straight forward (and were not changed).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `cell.editingAccessoryView` is set to nil in:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
 cell.editingAccessoryView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not implement tableView protocol's in your .h  .. you class interface should be like this

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```